# Test node.js file from website

Tags: node.js

I am completely a beginner in node.js and have no idea about its architecture.

I was just going through a tutorial where I have create a sample test node.js file (myapp.js) on my Godaddy server which listens to port 3000.

I have already installed nodejs on the server but not able to test it. I have tried by entering the but that does not work. Can anyone please guide me.

```
mywebsite.com:3000
```

Comment: Please refer the link, this may help you https://webapplog.com/node-server-port/

Comment: Have you started your `myapp.js` application?

Comment: @SamuelToh not yet mate. Still trying to figure out